# Can't push to origin main on Github (as of June 30)

Tags: github

I wanted to push to origin main, so I did:

```
git init
git fetch
git add .
git commit -m "commit name"
git push origin main
```

I get the following message when I try to push to origin main. I know it has something to do with an API request, a brownout, and using an authentication key instead of your link to main, but I don't understand how this works. Does anyone understand how to push?

```
remote: Password authentication is temporarily disabled as part of a brownout. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myusername/mygit.git': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a scheduled (temporary) brownout of standard github auth.
https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/#june-30-2021
It will be over in half an hour, but will become a permanent change in August.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what it is, but I'm curious how to (I'm a noob) configure a personal authentication token.